# How long does a French citizen have to wait to be able to enter Vietnam visa-free after having previously entered Vietnam with an e-visa?

Tags: visas, visa-free-entry, vietnam, french-citizens

French citizens currently (2019-07-30) might enter Vietnam visa-free (maximum length of stay: 15 days) or with an e-visa (maximum length of stay: 30 days; 25 USD).

I read on https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Visa_policy_of_Vietnam&oldid=907829633:

> A gap of at least 30 days between two visa-free visits is required. Must have a printout of onward ticket.

How long does a French citizen have to wait to be able to enter Vietnam visa-free after having previously entered Vietnam with an e-visa?